# How would one encrypt or protect a Drupal 7 Views Configuration Recipe from prying eyes?

Tags: 7, views

I spent quite a number of days developing a Views configuration recipe and I would like to protect it from other's stealing this by just viewing the Views page. Is there a module or a way to encrypt a views configuration recipe? Currently I built a site for a client and I don't want him just hiring someone that can just easily steal my views setup.

Comment: Views are GPL and it's configuration is stored as a PHP code - see how it looks when you export it. So it may be argued that you are creating sub-program that links to GPL views, and thus your creation is GPL too. If so, no one can "steal" it, as it is free to take. Of course given that access to the server is legitimate, breaking in would be a totally different case.

Comment: If it took many days to configure a views for you, you should let your client to pay for those days. You use free software with a free community support. Instead of thinking about encrypting your work, you should be thinking about writing a blog about it if it would help or spare time for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer... no.

Slightly longer answer...

Anything that views makes needs to be processed and displayed, there is no way (unless you make your own encrypted syntax then manually add a new view every single time then output it) to "encrypt" a view configuration.

Even PHP code that is encrypted can be decrypted. And that kind of encryption is ten times stronger (due to the fact it's at the C compiled level) then anything you could come up with using PHP.

If you really have a lot of time of your hands, you could redo the views module part that processes the configuration, create your own syntax that's encrypted to your own system, and store that (but please don't, and even that can be decrypted with a lot of effort.).

Comment: well i guess make it where it would be annoying to steal it if someone were to. like how some websites disable right click functionality, but obviously more experienced devs would be able to get around it if they really wanted to.

Comment: There is a big difference between disabling right click, and trying to disable viewing of something like a view configuration. Views configuration needs to be stored a specific way in order to be processed and the proper stuff displayed. There is no way to encrypt that without modifying views. And that's never a good idea.

Comment: @duckx My browser goes around "no right click" pseudo-security automatically without me even noticing it's there... And not because I want to steal, just because it annoys me. "Encrypted" views without serious rebuild of the module would be about as efficient.